# Difference between "safeguard the people's health" and "work to safeguard the people's health"

Tags: difference

A native English speaker has told me that "we need to protect/safeguard something" and "we need to work to protect/safeguard something" have different meanings. According to him, the first expression mentions only the intention - which is to ensure something (health, security, etc.) - while the second indicates the process and actions.

> The President said on Monday the country would defeat the current COVID outbreak.
> “We should resolutely safeguard the people's health.”

But in regard to this context, given that "safeguard the people's health" can mean processes and efforts like immunisation, I could not see the difference between "we need to safeguard the people's health" and "we need to work to safeguard the people's health". Could anyone please explain it to me?

Comment: Compare *We need to cure cancer* and *We need to work to cure cancer*. The former requires absolute and complete accomplishment of the goal, while the latter sets a less ambitious bar: exerting substantial effort *towards* the goal (which is that absolute and complete elimination of cancer).

Comment: So in your examples, safeguarding isn’t accomplished until the thing being safeguarded has been rendered safe.

Comment: Thank you very much! That helps a lot. Sorry to bother, but I still have one question. Could you please tell me what is the difference between "we need to resolutely safeguard the people's health" and "we need to work resolutely to safeguard the people's health"? A native has told me that "resolutely" could not modify a verb which implies the outcome, so I assume "safeguard" might imply the process rather than the goal in this context. I would like to know if "we need to resolutely safeguard the people's health" still requires complete accomplishment. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your initial understanding is the reverse of mine. To work to do something is like thinking about thinking, or trying to try. Both, not doing but making a fuss about it. Politics. Parents do not 'work to stop' their toddlers crossing the street, they stop them.

Comment: An adverb just gives the _manner_ in which the action of the verb is done.  One can say "we need to work resolutely" or "we need to resolutely work" just as much as one can say "resolutely safeguard"--which implies a form of "work" already.  The difference in meaning is minimal.

Comment: Thank you!! I have learned a lot from your replies.